# How does peer to peer architecture work in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

How the peer-to-peer Cassandra architecture really works ? I mean :

When the request hits the Cluster, it must hit some machine based on an IP, right ?

So which machine it will hit first ? : one of the nodes, or something in the Cluster who is responsible to balance and redirect the request to the right node ?

Could you describe what it is ? And how this differ from the Master/Folowers architecture ?

Comment: Hey Nassim, accidentally noticed your question. I lead an "Introduction to Apache Cassandra" workshop next week where I address this topic as well, jump in, it's free. https://www.eventbrite.com/e/an-introduction-to-apache-cassandratm-tickets-276726495397

Comment: hi @HadesArchitect thanks, I will register :)

Comment: I just hope it won't to high level like most talks about Cassandra are, they give no details about how the peer to peer architecture really works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purposes of my answer, I will use [the Java driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/) as an example since it is the most popular.

When you connect to a cluster using one of the driver, you need to configure it with details of your cluster including:

1. **Contact points** - the entry point to your cluster which is a comma-separated list of IPs/hostnames for some of the nodes in your cluster.
2. Login credentials - username and password if authentication is enabled on your cluster.
3. SSL/TLS certificate and credentials - if encryption is enabled on your cluster.

When your application starts, [a **control connection** is established with the first available node](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/control_connection/) in the list of **contact points**. The driver uses this control connection for admin tasks such as:

- get topology information about the cluster including node IPs, rack placement, network/DC information, etc
- get schema information such as keyspaces and tables
- subscribe to metadata changes including topology and schema updates

When you configure the driver with a [load-balancing policy](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/load_balancing/) (LBP), the policy will determine which node the driver will pick as the coordinator for each and every single query. By default, the Java driver uses a load balancing policy which picks nodes in the local datacenter. If you don't specify which DC is local to the app, the driver will set the local DC to the DC of the first contact point.

Each time a driver executes a query, it generates a **query plan** or a list of nodes to contact. This list of nodes has the following characteristics:

- A query plan is different for each query to balance the load across nodes in the cluster.
- A query plan only lists available nodes and does not include nodes which are down or temporarily unavailable.
- Nodes in the local DC are listed first and if the load-balancing policy allows it, remote nodes are included last.

The driver tries to contact each node in the query plan in the order they are listed. If the first node is available then the driver uses it as the coordinator. If the first node does not respond (for whatever reason), the driver tries the next node in the query plan and so on.

Finally, all nodes are equal in Cassandra. There is no active-passive, no leader-follower, no primary-secondary and this makes Cassandra a truly high availability (HA) cluster with no single point-of-failure. Any node can do the work of any other node and the load is distributed equally to all nodes by design.

If you're new to Cassandra, I recommend having a look at [datastax.com/dev](https://www.datastax.com/dev) which has lots of free hands-on interactive learning resources. In particular, the [Cassandra Fundamentals](https://www.datastax.com/learn/cassandra-fundamentals) learning series lets you learn the basic concepts quickly.

For what it's worth, you can also use the [Stargate.io](https://stargate.io/) data platform. It allows you to connect to a Cassandra cluster using APIs you're already familiar with. It is fully open-source so it's free to use. Here are links to the Stargate tutorials on datastax.com/dev: [REST API](https://www.datastax.com/dev/rest), [Document API](https://www.datastax.com/dev/documents-api), [GraphQL API](https://www.datastax.com/dev/graphql), and more recently [gRPC API](https://www.datastax.com/blog/available-now-grpc-apache-cassandra). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @Erick but I am not new to Cassandra, I am just preparing some Desing Interviews, and I want to know more about the under hood architecture of Cassandra

Answer (score 3):

Working with Cassandra, we have to remember two very important things: *data is partitioned* (split into chunks) and *data is replicated* (each chunk is stored on a few different servers). Partitioning is needed for scalability purposes while Replication serves High Availability. Given that Cassandra is designed to handle petabytes of data under huge pressure (dozens of millions of queries per second), and there is no single server able to handle such the load, each cluster server is responsible only for a range of data, not for the whole dataset. A node storing data you need for a particular query is called a "replica node". Notice that the different queries there will have different replica nodes.

Together, it brings a few implications:

1. We have to reach multiple servers during a single query to assure the data is consistent (read) / write data to all responsible servers (write).
2. How do we know which node is right for that particular query? What happens if a query hits a "wrong" node? How do we configure the application so it sends queries to the replica nodes?

Funny enough, as a developer you have to do one and only one thing: understand partitions and partition keys, and then Cassandra will take care of all the potential issues. Simple as that. When you design a table, you have to declare partition keys and the data placement will be based on that - automagically. Next thing, you have to always specify partition keys while doing your queries. That's it, your job is done, get yourself some coffee!

Meanwhile, Cassandra starts her job. Cassandra nodes are smart, they know data placement, they know what servers are responsible for the data you are writing, and they know the partitions - in Cassandra language it's called *token-aware*. That **does not matter** which server will receive the query, as literally **every server** is able to answer it. Any node that got the request (it's called query coordinator because it coordinates the query operations) will find replica nodes based on the placement of the partitions. With that, the query coordinator will execute the query, making proper calls to the replicas - the coordinator knows which nodes to ask because you did your part of the job and specified partition key value in the query, which is used for the routing.

In short, you can ask any of your cluster nodes to write/read your data, Cassandra is decentralized and you'll get it done. But how do we make it better and get directly to the replica to avoid bothering nodes that don't store our data?

> So which machine it will hit first ?

The travel of a request starts much earlier than we could think of - when your application starts, a Cassandra driver connects to a cluster and reads information about data placement: which partition is stored on which nodes, It means that driver knows which node has to be contacted for different queries. You got it right, a driver is token-aware too!

Token-aware drivers understand data placement and will route a query to a proper replica node. Answering the question: under normal circumstances, your query will first hit one of the replica nodes, this node will get answers or write data to the other replica nodes and that's it, we are good. In some rare situations, your query may hit a "wrong" non-replica server, but it doesn't really matter as it also will do the job, with just a minor delay - for example, if your Replication Factor = 3 (you have three replicas), and your query got to a "wrong" node, it will have to ask all three replicas while hitting the "right one" still require 2 network operations. It's not a big deal though as all the operations are done in parallel.

> how this differ from the Master/Folowers architecture

With leader/follower architecture, you can read from any server but you can write only to a leader server, which gives two issues:

1. Your app needs to know who is the leader (or you need to have a special proxy)
2. Single Point of Failure (SPoF) - if the leader is down, you can't write to the DB at all

With Cassandra's peer-to-peer architecture you can write to *any* of the cluster nodes, even if there are thousands of them. Of course, there is no SPoF.

P.S. Cassandra is an extremely powerful technology, but great power comes with great responsibility, it's quite complex too. If you plan to work with it, you better invest some time into learning to use it properly. I do suggest taking a Developer Path on the [academy.datastax.com](https://academy.datastax.com) (it's free!) or at least watch DataStax "Intro to Cassandra" [workshop](https://youtu.be/xF5y_n9viv8)

Answer (score 2):

It is based on the driver that you used to connect to the Cassandra™ cluster. Again, all nodes in the datacenter are one and same. It would connect to any of the nodes the `localdatacenter` that you have provided in driver configs based on the contact points configuration (i.e. `datastax-java-driver.basic.contact-points` in Java Driver).

For example, the Java driver (& most drivers logic will be the same) uses `system.peers.rpc-address` to connect to newly discovered nodes. For special network topologies, an address translation component can be plugged in.

- `advanced.address-translator` in the configuration.
- none by default. Also available: EC2-specific (for deployments that span multiple regions), or write your own.

Each node in the Cassandra cluster is uniquely identified by an IP address that the driver will use to establish connections.

for contact points, these are provided as part of configuring the `CqlSession` object;
for other nodes, addresses will be discovered dynamically, either by inspecting `system.peers` on already connected nodes, or via push notifications received on the control connection when new nodes are discovered by gossip.

More info can be found [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.13/manual/core/address_resolution/).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are asking how specifically Cassandra selects which Node gets hit with data and which ones doesn't.

There are two sides to this: the client and the servers

#### On the client

When a CQL Connection is established the client (if implemented in the client library and configured) usually also retrieves the [Topology](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/test/simulator/main/org/apache/cassandra/simulator/cluster/Topology.java) from the Cluster. A topology is the information about the token ownership inside the ring as well as information about quorums etc..

So the client itself can already make a decision on the next request what Node to contact for a certain amount of information due to *Consistent Hashing* of the primary keys in Cassandra. The client is aware who would be the right choice of Node to contact.

But still the client can choose not to use this information and just send the information to any node of the ring - the nodes will then forward the requests to the appropriate token owners -> See the next section.

#### In the Cluster

The same applies to the nodes themselves. If a client sends a request to a node it will simply look up the owner nodes in it's topology table and forward the request to exactly the nodes that do own this token.
It will always forward it to all of them so the data is consistent across the cluster. Depending on the replication factor it will return a success response to the client if the required replication is acknowledged by the cluster (eg. `LOCAL_QUORUM` with RF=3 will return a success response when 2 nodes acknowledge the receipt while the 3rd node is still pending).

If a node is detected as down or can't be reached the Command that would have been sent to the node is saved in the local `hints` table - a buffer that keeps all the operations that haven't been successfully sent to other nodes.

You can read more on [Hints in the Cassandra Docs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/hints.html)

Compared to a Leader/Follower architecture the Cassandra model is actually simpler and depends mostly on all involved nodes seeing all the mutation commands happening to the data they "own" via the tokens.

Comment: thanks @tigraine it's a little bit more clear, but suppose it's the first time the client is sending a query, which machine it will hit in the cluseter ? one of the nodes? or some loadbalancer in the cluster responsible to decide to which machine it should send it (or there's no such thing in cassandra)

Comment: for example in Redis, there's the Redis Cluster which receive the request and depending on then hash it will forward it to the right shard, and if yes there's such thing in Cassandra, could/should we consider it as a Single Point of Failer ?

Comment: It doesn't matter which node you hit. The first request will go randomly to any Node and the nodes will forward it to the appropriate owners.
All nodes are equal participants and are equipped to forward the data to others if they receive one :)