# How to do LOAD BALANCING and manage REPLICATION in our following PHP-PDO Configuration Code with Cassandra Database?

Tags: php, cassandra, nosql, load-balancing, database-replication

According to Wikipedia, **Load balancing refers to the process of distributing a set of tasks over a set of resources, with the aim of making their overall processing more efficient.**

So, wanting to use Cassandra PDO (https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/YACassandraPDO/), we want to know how to configure the connection to Cassandra for LEOD BALANCING support in order to better distribute the loads and or data processing on each of the servers:

```
$username = "test";
$password = "123456";

try {

    // $con = new PDO("mysql:dbname=ddd;host=localhost", "root", "");
    // $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    

    $con = new \PDO("cassandra:host=245.555.121.1;port=9160,host=192.168.1.1;port=9160,host=192.168.1.2;port=9160", $username, $password);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    
    $con->exec("CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS urlfetch with REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3 };";

    
    $con->exec("USE urlfetch");

}
catch(PDOExeption $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

1 - Personally, I am new to the use of Cassandra... I would therefore like to know if the layout of our PHP configuration code in Cassandra seems correct, especially at the level of `with REPLICATION = { 'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 3 }` where we did this without knowing exactly what it will return. Do you think maybe we should have put any value to `replication_factor` like for example: `'replication_factor': 100` ???

2 - How then, **to properly modify our configuration file or code above, to do LOAD BALANCING so as to allow Cassandra to effectively distribute the loads on the different servers ???**

Please guide us.

Comment: A few things - The PDO project you linked to seems dead. Current version of Cassandra is 4.0.x Also, when you develop your solution, note that SimpleStrategy is not suitable for production

Comment: The datastax-php driver https://github.com/datastax/php-driver is newer than the one you linked, but no new commits for almost 2 years.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. But how to arrange my Cassandra configuration file using https://github.com/datastax/php-driver so that it supports several servers and that especially it supports the use of LOAD BALANCING ??? I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly aware of the PHP Cassandra driver. If this one is implemented in the same way like Java, Python or Golang,

**you do not have to worry about load balancing at all**.

The most important part of working with Cassandra is to design a proper data model. If you did your work well, then you can relax, a cluster and a driver will take care of the proper balancing. If the data model is wrong, you can't fix it with a driver configuration, whatever you do.

The key to success is understanding the partitioning and partition keys: they should limit partition sizes to some reasonable numbers. I explain it a bit more in another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71299154/2214896) I gave to a similar question.

My recommendation would be:

1. Learn Cassandra fundamentals BEFORE running it in production: Cassandra is an awesome database but it is not an e-scooter but an Airbus of databases so if you take off without enough skills to land it safely, you are in trouble. At best, it's explained in a DataStax Academy course [DS201](https://academy.datastax.com/#/online-courses/6167eee3-0575-4d88-9f80-f2270587ce23).
2. Learn Cassandra Data Modeling and takes it seriously, overwise see p.1 It's the most common source of troubles if done wrong. It's explained in the next DataStax Academy course [DS220](https://academy.datastax.com/#/online-courses/ca2e1209-510b-44a6-97de-d5219d835319). The courses are free.

P.S. `replication_factor: 100` is a very bad idea, very bad.

Comment: One more thing. Cassandra nodes you configure there in PDO are NOT the nodes your app will use to store and retrieve data but to establish initial contact with a cluster and retrieve cluster details and token ranges (data distribution schema). Then the nodes responsible for storing your data will be contacted for real requests. In short, please don't go to production without learning how it works.